# C++ boost bad file descriptor

Tags: c++, rest, boost, boost-asio

Above is my code which im using calling from my browser and other client. But it doesnt seem to work. Is there anything wrong? I want to know on which ip im running my server and how this can be used to create a restful webservice.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;

std::string make_daytime_string() {
    using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    return ctime(&now);
}

int main() {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13));

        for (;;) {
            cout << "listening for socket" << endl;
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);

            cout << "listening for socket" << endl;
            std::string message = make_daytime_string();

            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), ignored_error);
        }
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify "it doesn't work"

Comment: the exe is started but when i try to connect it the host cannot be found.

Comment: You are not providing any logs.  Please try with GDB or specify exactly where is the problem. It would be really helpful ;)

Comment: I dont know where the problem is, can you run and let me know if its working for u.

Comment: I tested your server with putty and it works as expected: accepts connection on port 13, writes a string and immediately closes the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that you are not running the program with sufficient permission to open the privileged (<1024) port 13.

Trying with 1313 works for me (without administrative privileges)

Comment: if you want to run it on the same port run it as root

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar That's what I said, but I didn't want to assume a platform :) It's often better to explain the problem than to name 1 way (out of many) in which it can be solved. What about "Start Visual Studio with administrative privileges" or setuid the binary)